# Module classes in lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a lib file lister_extension.rb

```
module ListerExtension
 def lister
  puts "#{self.class}"
 end
end
```

And Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  extend ListerExtension
  def self.puts_hello
      puts "hello123123"
  end
end
```

All is good when I call this in `rails c`:

```
2.1.1 :003 > Post.lister
 Class
=> nil
```

But what happens when I want to add a class to my module?

For example:

```
module ListerExtension
 class ready
   def lister
    puts "#{self.class}"
   end
 end
end
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
```

When I call `Post.first` in rails c

Comment: Why did you put the class name as `ready` instead of `Ready` ?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR , in ruby you can´t extend with classes, you extend/include with modules

regards

updated: example for concern
include / extend with activesupport concern

```
module Ready
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # this is an instance method
  def lister
    ....
  end

  #this are class methods
  module ClassMethods
    def method_one(params)
      ....
    end

    def method_two
      ....
    end
  end
end
```

then in a ActiveRecord Model , like Post

```
class Post < AR
  include Ready
end
```

with this procedure you will get the instance methods and class methods for free, also you can set some macros like when use a included block,

```
module Ready

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :likes
  end
end
```

hope that helps,

regards

Comment: yeah , in rails is a good idea to use ActiveSupport::Concern to include extend clases, but you can do it without it, only with module with class methods, and instance methods , and then include the instance methods, and extend with the class methods

Comment: Do you have an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the doc for `extend`:

> Adds to obj the instance methods from each module given as a
>   parameter.

Hence, you can't access this class through extended class. Have a look into including modules instead of extending them (read about `ActionSupport::Concern` module as well) or have a go with `self.extended` method (ref [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-extended))

Comment: I thought extend makes all the functions class functions and include makes them instances functions

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy not quite, extend make all the method of a module available as singleton methods of an other class/module.