# How do I include a class from lib folder in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this class in my libs folder

```
class AboutMe
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'api.about.me'



    def initialize(email)
        @options = { :query => {:email => service, :extended => true } }
    end

    def search
      self.class.get("/api/v2/json/users/search", @options)
    end
end
```

And I have a model

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  def some_method
  end
end
```

How do I include that class to be used in my model?

Comment: When you say "include", do you want to mixin `def some_method` in your model or just call `some_method` from your model?

Comment: Dear! It is minimum Ruby knowledge..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is require the particular class in your model.

For example: Add the following line at the top of your model `Record`

`require 'about_me'`

Alternatively, you can autoload `lib/` folder including all subdirectories in your `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Wow, I am so stupid. This was right in front of me and I had already included the lib folder. Question for you @Kirti, what happens if the class is within a module as such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188741/module-classes-in-lib-folder?noredirect=1#comment35489117_23188741

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy I have seen that question. The answers are correct. `Ready` should be a module which you could easily access with the `Post` model.

Comment: so it shouldn't be a class at all?